# Understanding old notation from set theory / game theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, game-theory

I am reading an old paper from 1949 by Shapely, Karlin and Bohnenblust titled ["Solutions of Discrete Two-persons Games"](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/603812.pdf)

They introduce the following definitions

[image]

However I am unsure how these definitions should be interpreted. It doesn't seem like $\Sigma$ represents a sum operation here as the sets $I_{1}(x)$ and $J_{2}(y)$ seem to be sets of indices, so I don't see a reason why you would want to add elements of the sets together. Should I interpret $\Sigma$ here as a union of the sets of indices instead? If so how should I interpret $\Pi$? Once again it doesn't seem like a standard product operator?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like union to me. Each $I_1(x)$ is a set of indices, as you mention, and after applying the "$\Sigma$" operation, the result is used to test set inclusion.

In words, the operation appears to collect all of the indices of pure strategies which are active in *any* optimal mixed strategy.

I suspect the "product" $\Pi$ is product in the sense of sets, i.e. elements of its resultant are ordered tuples. Without seeing how $I_2$ is used later, that's only a guess.

Comment: For *disjoint* sum it's indeed used today as well.

Comment: I see, thank you. I am still slightly confused about $\Pi$ as the definition of $X_{\ell}$ seems to imply that $I_{1}(x)$ can be a subset of $I_{2}$.

Comment: @NickBishop: Yes, that pretty much excludes the Cartesian product. I strongly suspect that $\prod$ is used here for the intersection, $\bigcap$.